# Role Based Access Control Field level in Symfony/PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, rbac

I have been trying to figure out about this from a long time. I have asked in most of the forums and groups and didn't get satisfied answers for this question. Now, I probably realised that I missed one of the main forums. Here is my question

1. I want to have a simple RBAC in php.
2. The RBAC should have the simple role based access control for tables/Modals/Entities.
3. It also should be able to control the field wise access control, like one user might get a chance to edit/view x column which other user can't.
4. I should also be able to control condition based access control, like if the user is from India, I might restrict certain options, if he is from Pakistan, I might show only few basic options. If he is from UK, he might be able to see all the options.
5. I don't want to put if and else conditions everywhere for these things as these conditions might constantly change over time.
6. It would be good if i get something written on top of symfony's security model. Otherwise, I will have to rewrite the entire security features.

So, Please suggest me the following

1. Best architecture for this kind of scenario.
2. Is there already any symfony/PHP libraries available to support this use case?

Comment: Symfony voters would be your starting point: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html But your question is just a tiny bit broad.

Comment: I thought Symfony has its own ACL?

Comment: Symfony does indeed have it's own acl component: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html Bit challenging to use.  In general it's best to see if voters can meet your requirements.  But if you really need ultimate control then the acl is there.

Comment: Hi all, as I could see symfony acls or voters are going to help me in achieving the condition based access. How would you do for a field level. Can you guys help me with an example or reference?

Answer (score 0):

the security bundle of oro platform  might be what you want, the challenge is that bundle is deeply coupled with the oro ecosystem. however , you can learn its basic ideas from  that bundle.